# html select doesn't display default option

Tags: html

I have a select which doesn't show 'Default' option. It looks like this:

```
<select id="sortBy" name="sortBy" onchange="if(guestLightbox()) {sortPropertyBy(this.value);}">
<option class="quality_score_member hideWhenResaleMLS" value="quality_score_member-desc">Default</option>
<option class="auction_date hideWhenForeclosures hideWhenPreForeclosures hideWhenResaleMLS hideWhenFSBOOrRentalOrRTO" value="auction_date">Auction Date</option>
<option class="home_score-desc" value="home_score-desc">SmartZip HomeScore</option>
<option class="investor_score-desc" value="investor_score-desc">SmartZip InvestorScore</option>
<option class="amount" value="amount">Price (low to high)</option>
<option class="amount-desc" value="amount-desc">Price (high to low)</option>
<option class="living_area_square_feet" value="living_area_square_feet">Square Feet (low to high)</option>
<option class="living_area_square_feet-desc" value="living_area_square_feet-desc">Square Feet (high to low)</option>
<option class="scrape_date-desc" value="scrape_date-desc">Most Recent</option>
<option class="sale_type" value="sale_type">Sale Type</option>
<option class="property_record_type" value="property_record_type">Property Type</option>
</select>
```

Could somebody explain why?

Thanks.

Comment: What do the CSS classes `quality_score_member hideWhenResaleMLS` contain?

Comment: that class actually doesn't exists.

Comment: you were right it is because of the class but dont know why.

Comment: sorry bro I tried but it doen't allow me to accept it anymore. will do it next time :)

Answer (score 2):

The only reason I can see for this is one of your CSS classes

```
quality_score_member hideWhenResaleMLS
```

defining a `display: none`, `visibility: hidden`, or some other element-hiding CSS property.

> **Edit:** turns out it's jQuery removing the option. Well, that was the other only possible reason ;)

Comment: When I am viewing in Elements section of Google Chrome that element is just excluded.

Comment: just doesn't appear. I found where it comes from 
$('.hideWhen${saleCategoryType}').remove();
thanks you where right

Comment: @George that's the reason then. *Why* that is in your code, I don't know - I'm sure it has a purpose

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this error quite a few times when someone is developing a page and refreshing to see the updates.  Your browser will usually display whatever option you had selected last.  This includes if you add an option above or below the previously selected option.

Try going to the page again from scratch (not using refresh) and tell us if that solves your problem.

Comment: no no that's not an issue. In fact, there are several different tabs that consume this HTML and only one of them is not displaying the first option.

Answer (score 0):

Working here on [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2QKD/)

```
<select id="sortBy" name="sortBy" onchange="if(guestLightbox()) {sortPropertyBy(this.value);}">
    <option class="quality_score_member hideWhenResaleMLS" value="quality_score_member-desc">Default</option>
    <option class="auction_date hideWhenForeclosures hideWhenPreForeclosures hideWhenResaleMLS hideWhenFSBOOrRentalOrRTO" value="auction_date">Auction Date</option>
    <option class="home_score-desc" value="home_score-desc">SmartZip HomeScore</option>
    <option class="investor_score-desc" value="investor_score-desc">SmartZip InvestorScore</option>
    <option class="amount" value="amount">Price (low to high)</option>
    <option class="amount-desc" value="amount-desc">Price (high to low)</option>
    <option class="living_area_square_feet" value="living_area_square_feet">Square Feet (low to high)</option>
    <option class="living_area_square_feet-desc" value="living_area_square_feet-desc">Square Feet (high to low)</option>
    <option class="scrape_date-desc" value="scrape_date-desc">Most Recent</option>
    <option class="sale_type" value="sale_type">Sale Type</option>
    <option class="property_record_type" value="property_record_type">Property Type</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the attribute `SELECTED` (or, respectively, `selected='selected'` or alike [upd]) with `OPTION`.